# Looking up a string within a text file and reading the whole line

Tags: vb.net

Good afternoon all.
I am currently creating a program that has the ability to look up an inputted registration number in the format (LL/NN/LLL) within a text file database.The database is a text file which contains data featuring: Registration Number, Owner Name, Address. If the inputted registration is found within the database, the program must be able to output the details (name and address) to a new file.
Here is what I have so far:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
Dim reg_str As String
Dim speed_int As Integer
Dim limit_int As Integer
Dim filepath As String = "StandardVehicles.txt"


Private Sub cmbCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbCalculate.Click
    Dim AllText As String = "StandardVehicles.txt"
    Dim Found As Boolean
    Dim result As String = AllText
    If Not IsNumeric(txtSpeed.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid speed!")
        Return
    End If
    If Not IsNumeric(txtLimit.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid speed limit!")
        Return
    End If
    reg_str = txtReg.Text
    speed_int = txtSpeed.Text
    limit_int = txtLimit.Text
    Dim FindString = IO.File.ReadAllText(AllText)
    Dim LookFor As String = (txtReg.Text)
    Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
    If FindString.Contains(LookFor) And speed_int > limit_int Then
        Found = True
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Not Found. Please Try Again.")
        Found = False
    End If
    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                   FileIO.TextFieldParser(
                     "StandardVehicles.txt")
        MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.SetDelimiters("#")
        Dim currentRow As String()
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()

                Dim currentField As String
                For Each currentField In currentRow
                    If Found = True Then
                        MsgBox("Found: " & LookFor)
                        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("Speeders.txt", True)
                        file.WriteLine(currentField.ToString & " was caught speeding!")
                        file.Close()
                    End If
                Next
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                        FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
                "is not valid and will be skipped.")
            End Try
        End While
    End Using
End Sub
End Class
```

The Database is in the following format:

> QW12YIB DEAN EVANS 21 UNNAMED LANE, UNNAMED TOWN, UNNAMED COUNTY, UK#

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems very inefficient to open, read and parse that file each time.  You could read it into a `List(of MotorVehicleRegistration)` (or whatever) and just search that

Comment: Best approach > list of custom class that has all these values. As Plutonix wrote your approach is really inefficient. How to get info use 'string.split'. First split by "," and later by " ".

Comment: What output do you get? Are you having a specific problem? This would help get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
dim registartion as string = currentRow.substring(0,6)

dim name as string = currentRow.substring(8,GetNthIndex(currentRow," ",3)
dim address as string = currentRow.substring(GetNthIndex(currentRow," ",3), GetNthIndex(currentRow,",",1)
dim town as string = currentRow.substring(GetNthIndex(currentRow,",",1), GetNthIndex(currentRow,",",2)
dim county as string = currentRow.substring(GetNthIndex(currentRow,",",2), GetNthIndex(currentRow,",",3)





Public Function GetNthIndex(s As String, t As Char, n As Integer) As Integer
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To s.Length - 1
        If s(i) = t Then
            count += 1
            If count = n Then
                Return i
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return -1
End Function
```

Comment: I am only getting this when I set Textbox1.text to myreader; "System.substring()'

Comment: Is that bad or good? If you have any problems with getting and using text perhaps use streamreader. here is some useful link http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets8p3.html